# Can JMockit MockUp mock toString()?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, jmockit

Consider the following sample `MockUp` of a class `Foo` that intercepts `Bar` in the constructor and then implements `toString()` in terms of `Bar`;

```java
public class FooStub extends MockUp<Foo> {

    private Bar bar;

    @Mock
    public void $init(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    @Mock
    public String toString() {
        return bar.toString();
    }
}
```

If `Foo` happens to override `toString()` all works fine. Otherwise though, you get a `IllegalArgumentException` : "Matching real methods not found for the following mocks". I understand from here that JMockit does not look in base classes and therefore cannot find a `toString()` method to mock.

Assuming I can't modify the Foo class (in reality I can, but just for the sake of argument), is there any way to mock `toString()` just for this `Foo` class?

To be clear, I want to mock all instances of this class, not just one instance (that has easy solutions that do no require a `MockUp`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmockit: Can't mock method toString of net.android.Uri class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561351/jmockit-cant-mock-method-tostring-of-net-android-uri-class)

Answer (score 0):

**JMockit** will mock all super-classes up the class hierarchy **up to**, **but excluding** `java.lang.Object`.

You could define `private final` class in your test which extends `Bar` by overriding `toString()` which delegates to `Bar`'s `toString()` by calling `super.toString()`:

```
private final class Baz extends Bar {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do in your mock is to delegate via `Baz` not `Bar`.

This way you got concrete yet transparent implementation of `toString()` which you can mock without touching `Bar` class which is potentially out of your control.