# Jmockit: Can't mock method toString of net.android.Uri class

Tags: java, android, junit, jmockit

IDE: Android Studio 2.2.2 | Jmockit: 2.1 | Java: 1.8.0_102-b14

I tried to mock method toString() of class net.android.Uri. All method on this class could mock OK, but toString() method.

```
@Test
public void method(@Mocked final Uri uri) throws Exception {
    new NonStrictExpectations() {
            {
                uri.getHost();
                result = "sendViewLog";
                uri.getAuthority();
                result = "getAuthority";
                uri.getEncodedFragment();
                result = "getEncodedFragment";
                uri.getPort();
                result = 8080;
                uri.toString(); // <-------
                result = "helloWorld";
            }
        };      

    sut.method();
}
```

**Result:** But toString() returns null value, all method above were mocked.
Could you give me some solution method resolve this problem.

**PS1:** 
I realized that when i hover to toString method inside Expectations block. It shows this warning message:

> Reports any calls to specific methods where the result of that call is
>   ignored. Both methods specified in the inspection's settings and
>   methods annotated with org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract(pure=true)
>   are checked. For many methods, ignoring the result is perfectly
>   legitimate, but for some methods it is almost certainly an error.
>   Examples of methods where ignoring the result of a call is likely to
>   be an error include java.io.inputStream.read(), which returns the
>   number of bytes actually read, any method on java.lang.String or
>   java.math.BigInteger, as all of those methods are side-effect free and
>   thus pointless if ignored.

**PS2:**
When I check null by uri instance, it passes.
But, code from client which I want to check is *uri.toString().contains("/video")*
Cause *uri.toString()* == null, so *contains("/video")* throws NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from developer:

> Yes, only implemented (with a body, not abstract) toString() methods can be mocked.

https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/381